# How do I set the FileName value when doing an upload from the API?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics v3 library in my code to upload data to a custom dataset. I noticed that when I upload this data from the UI (browser), the filename parameter is automatically populated for me.(*screenshot below*)

[image: Uploaded from Browser]

I am trying to find the answer in this [guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData)

Here is my code:

```
            var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = cr,
                    ApplicationName = "Analytics API Sample"
                });

            //Upload the contents of a file to a custom data set.
            try
            {
                const string accountId = "65651631";
                const string webPropertyId = "UA-65651631-1";
                const string customDataSourceId = "WMIjJuXXSyKZC8x8YOnbYQ";
                FileStream realCsv = new 
                   FileStream(@"C:\Users\Downloads\TestData - template.csv", FileMode.Open);
                var upload = service.Management.Uploads.UploadData(accountId, webPropertyId,
                    customDataSourceId, realCsv, "application/octet-stream").Upload();

                realCsv.Close();
                realCsv.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the client libraries strip the file name from the `POST` request. However if you formulate the request yourself say with `CURL` the filename will remain in the `POST` body and be properly labeled in the web UI.

```
curl -X POST -H "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/webproperties/<PROPERTYID>/customDataSources/<DATASOURCEID>/uploads?uploadType=media" -F "upload=@filename.csv;type=application/octet-stream"
```

I know it is not the answer you were hoping for but I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but you've still provided me with a valuable piece of information. Thanks